# coroutine/reactive extensions - write lines

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, coroutine

I'm using the two functions to read and write huge files (write to multiple files). I want to keep the file operation in the functions because the lines may be read/write from other sources.

**Update:**
C# doesn't really have coroutine. Is it a good use case for Reactive extensions?

```
foreach (var line in ReadFrom("filename"))
{
    try 
    {
        .... // Some actions based on the line
        var l = ..... 
        WriteTo("generatedFile1", l);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        var l = ..... // get some data from line, e and other objects etc.
        WriteTo("generatedFile2", l);
    }
}
```

The following function open the file once until all the lines are read and then close and release the resource.

```
    private static IEnumerable<string> ReadFrom(string file)
    {
        string line;
        using (var reader = File.OpenText(file))
        {
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                yield return line;
        }
    }
```

However, the following function, which write the lines instead of read lines, open and close the file for each line it writes. Is it possible to implement it in a way so it only open the file once and continue to write to the file until EOF is sent?

```
    private static void WriteTo(string file, string line)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(file)) // Remove and recreate the file if existing
            using (var tw = File.CreateText(file))
            {
                tw.WriteLine(line);
            }
        else
            using (var tw = new StreamWriter(file, true))
            {
                tw.WriteLine(line);
            }
    }
```

Comment: Your first method can be replaced with `File.ReadLines` and second methods can be replaced with `File.WriteLines`

Comment: Is it a requirement that you process one line at a time (e.g. very big file)? Otherweise, File.ReadAllLines is fine.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: you just need to be careful that you don't use `File.WriteAllLines("path",File.ReadLines("path"))` which will try to write to a file which you are currently reading.

Comment: @WeSt You should basically never use `File.ReadAllLines` in my mind.  It's an antiquated method.  You should virtually always be using `File.ReadLines` instead.  The method the OP has here is designed to do pretty much the same thing, except that it doesn't have a bug that's in `File.ReadLines`.

Comment: @Servy: too generalized, for example if you want to modify an existing file you cannot use `File.ReadLines` without reading it into memory. You also cannot use it a second time(f.e. `var lines=File.ReadLines(..); string header=lines.First();` If you now try to use `lines` again you'll see an `ObjectDisposedException`.

Comment: @Sevy the above method and File.ReadLines are not equal. Since 'yield return' is used, the 'reader.ReadLine()' is called when the 'IEnumerable<string>' is iterated. Hence, not all lines are present at a given point in time (as far as I know).

Comment: @TimSchmelter In such cases (which I would usually try to avoid, i.e. through a second temp file) I'd use `ToList` to materialize the query.  This makes it explicit that the materialization is important.

Comment: @WeSt What do you think `ReadLines` does?  It streams the data, of course, just like this does.  You seem to be mistaking `ReadLines` with `ReadAllLines`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yep, that's [what I consider a bug in ReadLines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25646203/writing-all-lines-to-a-file?noredirect=1#comment40072882_25646203).  (Of course I'm not sure if MS can fix it at this point, as it'd be a breaking change and some people are likely depending on its current behavior.)  The OP's re-creation of `ReadLines` doesn't have that bug.

Comment: Just FYI, C# certainly does have a native coroutine: async/await.  Rx also provides a coroutine wrapper that depends on async/await.  See my [blog post](http://davesexton.com/blog/post/async-iterators.aspx) and [this discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/rx/thread/6e0ead42-4d89-429d-b6a8-d422cf673390).

Comment: [Rxx](https://rxx.codeplex.com) also provides several operators that LINQifies this sort of thing.  See the [operators](https://rxx.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Main/Source/Rxx/System/IO/StreamExtensions.cs) and [somewhat-related labs](https://rxx.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Main/Testing/Rxx.Labs/Reactive/ObservableFileLab.cs).

Answer (score 6):

Just use `File.WriteAllLines`.  It will write all of the lines in a sequence to a file, and it won't open/close the file for each line.

Comment: The lines are generated by the code and it may be millions of lines.

Comment: @dc7a9163d9 Okay.  That's fine.  This method will read the lines from the sequence individually and write them out without buffering the entire content into memory.  You can have billions of lines if you want.

Comment: Maybe make the main loop a function yield returning `IEnumerable<string>` and pass it to `File.WriteAllLines`.

Comment: @dc7a9163d9 That's an option, but you likely don't need to do that.  If you're input is being read in from another file then you already have a method to stream the data from one file, you can simply manipulate the data while it's streaming using LINQ and write the data out to another file on the other end of your pipeline.

Comment: `File.WriteAllLines()` doesn't accept `IEnumerable<string>` and it needs to be cast to cast using `ToList()` or `ToArray`, which will create a copy in memory? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394165/using-linq-to-update-string-array

Comment: The project uses .Net 3.5.

Comment: @dc7a9163d9 Then you'll need to replicate what the 4.5 overload does by re-creating the method, accepting an `IEnumerable`, iterating through the lines, and writing them all to a writer.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the entire second method, and replace the call with `var writer = new StreamWriter(file, true)`, as [that constructor creates the file if it does not exist](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb(v=vs.110).aspx).

You can then use `writer.WriteLine()` until you're done writing, and `Dispose()` it afterwards.

Comment: But he's not concerned with creating the file. He doesn't want to open and close it repeatedly just to write a single line.

Comment: All I'm saying is that it's a useless method, and OP's problem can be solved by doing what I state in my answer. OP should give more context (like "I don't want to keep a reference") if this doesn't answer his question. OP wants to not open and close the file for every line he writes, well, then he should keep a reference to a writer somewhere (see: my answer) or write all lines at once (see: @Servy's answer).